# getting vulkan error while running vulkaninfo

Tags: nvidia

I'm getting this error when I use the command vulkaninfo ,im using Nvidia-driver-460 on Ubuntu 18.04

```
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : loader_icd_scan: Can not find 'ICD' object in ICD JSON file /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_layers.json.  Skipping ICD JSON
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : loader_scanned_icd_add: Could not get 'vkCreateInstance' via 'vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr' for ICD libGLX_nvidia.so.0
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
'DISPLAY' environment variable not set... skipping surface info
/build/vulkan-tools-136mCR/vulkan-tools-1.1.126.0+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:399: failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a correct binaries? Looks like something 64 bits tries to load 32 bits libs

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so

> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so

`uname -a` would help and also `file vulkaninfo`

Comment: $uname -a #140-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 28 05:20:47 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux and when i run file vulkaninfo it show there is no such file

Comment: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so and these i don't how they got installed, are they affecting Vulkan to run? if so how can I remove those?

Comment: to find out what package has installed a file you can do `dpkg -S libvulkan_radeon.so`

Comment: this is the result of the above command "mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so"

Comment: and if you do `file \`which vulkaninfo\`` ? My guess is that vulkaninfo is 64 bits but those rivers that fail to load are somehow 32 bits. Seems like your PC is 64 bits then it would be sensible to install 64 bit version of those drivers. But I can't figure out how you've ended up with 32 bit drivers on 64 bit machine.

Comment: /usr/bin/vulkaninfo: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=8ca9c027d4a9c15c744337b00f8e0f32145d4608, stripped this is the result of file 'which vulkaninfo' ,how to force vulkan to use x86-64 drivers ?

Comment: One option would be to first see what architecture apt-cache will propose to you. You can try `apt-cache show mesa-vulkan-drivers` and see what Architecture the packege proposes to install

Comment: Package: mesa-vulkan-drivers
Architecture: amd64
Version: 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1

 this is the outcome of apt-cache show mesa-vulkan-drivers

Comment: you can try to reinstall then the mesa-vulkan-driver. But it can mess up your system

Comment: As you can see for yourself the proper drivers for your system are 64 bits, but somehow you got 32 bit version. Is life worth living knowing that you have 32 bits drivers instead of 64? you can attempt `sudo apt-get reinstall mesa-vulkan-drivers`. But again at your own risk. Do a backup first if you're not comfortable with command line interface.